# Create smooth tab transition JQUERY

Tags: jquery

So i have this JQUERY to transition between tabs. How can i edit it so the transition is smooth and not instant.

Code:

```js
$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
  var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

  $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
  $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

  $(this).addClass('current');
  $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
 })
```

Thanks!

Comment: Whats the point in adding you code a snippet if it fails outright? You have not bothered to put jQuery in your snippet as a start. Where is your HTML?

Comment: @ProEvilz, code works. Just no transition. FadeIn and FadeOut needs to be added somewhere. This is all i need.

Comment: This is not the code actually switching to different tabs. will you try to show that code?